# Failing case during testing react component

Tags: reactjs, karma-runner, enzyme

I've got problem with testing react component. Here's my code.

```
// Component textfield-input.jsx
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import HelpComponent from '../../atoms/help-component'

export default function TextField(props) {
    const { helpMessage, label, error, ...rest } = props
    return (
        <div className="text-field">
            <label htmlFor={props.name} className="name-label">
                {label}
                {helpMessage ?
                    <HelpComponent message={helpMessage} /> : null
                }
            </label>
            {props.required ? <span className="dot">*</span> : null}
            <input className={`input ${error ? 'error' : ''}`} {...rest} />
            {error && (<span className="error-text">{error}</span>)}
        </div>
    )
}

TextField.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    helpMessage: PropTypes.string,
    error: PropTypes.string,
    required: PropTypes.bool,
}
```

This is my TextField component.

```
// Help Component
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

export default function HelpComponent(props) {
    const direction = props.direction || 'right'

    return (
        <i
            className="fa fa-question-circle"
            data-toggle="tooltip"
            data-placement={direction}
            title={props.message}
            aria-hidden="true"
        />
    )
}

HelpComponent.propTypes = {
    direction: PropTypes.string,
    message: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

This is my HelpComponent that is used in TextField component.

```
// Test textfield-input.spec.jsx
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

import TextField from '../../src/components/molecules/form/textfield-input'

describe('Unit: TextField component', () => {
    let component
    let props = {
        name: 'text',
        label: 'Text',
    }
    const COMPONENT = <TextField {...props} />

    beforeEach(() => {
        component = shallow(COMPONENT)
    })

    it('should be react component', () => {
        expect(component.exists()).to.be.true
    })

    it('should render proper TextField', () => {
        expect(component.find('.text-field').exists()).to.be.true
        expect(component.find('.name-label').contains(props.label)).to.be.true
        expect(component.find(`input[name="${props.name}"]`).exists()).to.be.true
    })

    it('should render help message', () => {
        component.setProps({ helpMessage: 'help message' })
        expect(component.find('.fa').exists()).to.be.true
    })
})
```

Test spec. Should test TextField input. But **'should render help message'** case is failing. Any other case works.

**AssertionError: expected false to be true**. But it should be true.

**Edit:** It's even worse after switching form shallow to mount. All cases fails then - exception for 'should be react component' - pass.

**Solution:** @shota is right. I should use *mount* instead of *shallow*. But my test cases were also wrong. This is the right way.

```
expect(component.find('.name-label').text()).to.equal(props.label)
```

instead of

```
expect(component.find('.name-label').contains(props.label)).to.be.true
```

Now everything works fine.

Thx~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `shallow` rendering, that is why it is failing. When using shallow rendering the child components won't be rendered but will stay as components.

So in your case, it won't go down into the child component and test whether the class exists there, but test immediate nodes in render method and raw components without rendering them.

So if you need to test child components too, you need [full dom rendering](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md)

Comment: You need to set up jsdom to make Enzyme mount to work, take a look here: http://blog.ricardofilipe.com/post/react-enzyme-tdd-tutorial

Comment: Do i need jsdom with Karma? 

I'm using Karma, Mocha, Chai, Sinon and Enzyme.

Comment: How do you use Karma and Mocha together, they are both test runners?

Comment: I'm not using them together :) my bad. Thx for help. I've edited question again with solution.